# DAX problem "The expression refers to multiple columns. It cannot be converted to a scalar value."

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an issue with a DAX formula in Power BI. I want to calculate how our purchase share for each country evolves over the years. I have tried to write a DAX formula but received the following error message:

'The expression refers to multiple columns. It cannot be converted to a scalar value.

I have tested this formula:

```
Purchase Share per Country =
VAR TotalIn2022 =
    SUMX (
        FILTER ( 'Table1', 'Table1'[Order Date].[Year] = 2022 ),
        'Table1'[Total Amount (HKD)]
    )
VAR TotalIn2023 =
    SUMX (
        FILTER ( 'Table1', 'Table1'[Order Date].[Year] = 2023 ),
        'Table1'[Total Amount (HKD)]
    )
RETURN
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( 'Table1', 'Table1'[Factory Country] ),
        "Purchase Share 2022",
            DIVIDE (
                SUMX (
                    FILTER ( 'Table1', 'Table1'[Order Date].[Year] = 2022 ),
                    'Table1'[Total Amount (HKD)]
                ),
                TotalIn2022
            ),
        "Purchase Share 2023",
            DIVIDE (
                SUMX (
                    FILTER ( 'Table1', 'Table1'[Order Date].[Year] = 2023 ),
                    'Table1'[Total Amount (HKD)]
                ),
                TotalIn2023
            )
    )
```

But I'm encountering an error message: 'The expression refers to multiple columns. It cannot be converted to a scalar value.

What do you think, can this problem be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to save a table expression as a measure. A measure requires a scalar output, but if the measure expression results in a columnar or table-like output, you will usually get this type of error.

Try the expression in the new table dialog, instead of a new measure dialog.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Yes, it's true that I wanted to create a measure. I tried using the code to create a new table instead, and it "worked" to some extent. However, I ended up with 100% share for each country and a total sum of 600%. Do you have any suggestions on how I should adjust the code to get a correct calculation?

One more question: is it possible to modify the code to create a measure instead?

Comment: For your first question, wrap the expressions you are adding in `ADDCOLUMNS` in `CALCULATE` to apply a row context transition. For your second question, yes, a measure can most likely be written to calculate what you want, but that isn’t what your original question is about :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, Markus! Everything worked out, and I wasn't aware that you could create a new table using DAX, not just measures. I've learned that as well :-)